# Linter suddenly super strict after upgrading to Angular 6

Tags: angular, lint

I just upgraded to Angular 6 and I'm trying to deploy it. I'm having a hell of a time though. My newest error is a suddenly super-strict linter. After building and running `firebase deploy`, my command line throws somewhere between 1,000 and 5,000 errors, preventing me from deploying my app. These are errors like `" should be '`, `trailing whitespace`, `comment must start with a space`, etc. All these 'errors' in these components used to deploy just fine in my Angular 5 project.

- Why did it get all strict on me all of a sudden?
- Can it be relaxed a bit?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rolling back your `tslint.json` to the version you were using before?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following line to my tslint.json file in my app's root directory to lower the severity level to warnings instead of compilation-stopping errors:

`"defaultSeverity": "warn",`

Thanks to rock007 for his [post](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/133#issuecomment-383793976)